# how to hunt down memory leak valgrind says doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

I have a program that accepts data from a socket, does some quality control and assorted other conditioning to it, then writes it out to a named pipe.  I ran valgrind on it and fixed all the memory leaks that originally existed.  I then created a 'demo' environment on a system where I had 32 instances of this program running, each being fed unique data and each outputting to it's own pipe.  We tested it and everything looked to be fine.  Then I tried stress testing it by boosting the rate at which data is sent in to an absurd rate and things looked to be good at first...but my programs kept consuming more and more memory until I had no resources left.

I turned to valgrind and ran the exact same setup except with each program running inside valgrind using leak-check=full.  A few odd things happened.  First, the memory did leak, but only to the point where each program had consumed .9 % of my memory (previously the largest memory hog had a full 6% of my memory).  With valgrind running the CPU cost of the programs shot up and I was now at 100% cpu with a huge load-average, so it's possible the lack of available CPU caused the programs to all run slowly enough that the leak took too long to manifest.  When I tried stopping these programs valgrind showed no direct memory leaks, it showed some potential memory leaks but I checked them and I don't think any of them represent real memory leaks; and besides which the possible memory leak only showed as a few kilobytes while the program was consuming over 100 MB.  The reachable (non-leaked) memory reported by valgrind was also in the KB range, so valgrind seems to believe that my programs are consuming a fraction of the memory that Top says they are using.

I've run a few other tests and got odd results.  A single program, even running at triple the rate my original memory-leak was detected at, never seems to consume more than .9% memory, two programs leak up to 1.9 and 1.3% memory respectively but no more etc, it's as if the amount of memory leaked, and the rate at which it leaks, is somehow dependent on how many instances of my program are running at one time; which makes no sense, each instance should be 100% independent of the others.

I also found if I run 32 instances with only one instance running in valgrind the valgrinded instance (that's a word if I say it is!) leaks memory, but at a slower rate than the ones running outside of valgrind.  The valgrind instance will still say I have no direct leaks and reports far less memory consumption then Top shows.

I'm rather stumped as to what could be causing this result, and why valgrind refuses to be aware of the memory leak.  I thought it might be an outside library, but I don't really use any external libraries; just basic C++ functions/objects.  I also considered it could be the data written to the output pipe to fast causing the buffer to grow indefinitely, but 1) there should be an upper limit that such a buffer can grow and 2) once memory has been leaked if I drop the data input rate to nothing the memory stays consumed rather then slowly dropping back to a reasonable amount.

Can anyone give me a hint as to where I should look from here?  I'm totally stumped as to why the memory is behaving this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure its a leak, and not just some part of your programming collecting memory? have you tried massif?

Comment: I've hit similar problems myself (though not as quirky) and I'm very interested in any feedback you get. One suggestion: could you clarify the OS / version you're using? I assume it's a Linux dist.

Comment: Valgrind runs your program in a sandbox and does a huge amount of processing. You should expect it to have much higher CPU usage and much slower performance than the same application running out of valgrind. I would consider whether during stress testing the program creates extra buffers to hold data that could not make it to the pipe and that is growing (not leaked, just growing as you cannot keep the pace).

Comment: Plasma, My program shouldn't be growing more then a few KB of memory if written correctly.  I wouldn't cross out the possibility that it is written incorrectly, but then I would think Valgrind would have showed the 'reachable' memory as much larger then it was wouldn't it?  I never tried massif as...well I hadn't heard of it before.  I'll look at it as soon as I can get back to my desk and see if it can help any.

Comment: I'm running centos at the moment.  I'm using C++ but not C++11 if that helps any.  to david, I should not buffer more then, at most, 6 seconds of data; the data needs to be timely.  Iv'e done the math on size of input vector, number of vectors per seconed etc and the memory needed to store that much is about equal to what valgrind says I'm using when one combineds possible leak and reachable code (the possible leak is from my manually kiling to code before it could send the last 'batch' of buffered data so that that batch wasn't properly freed yet)

Comment: The fact that it only appears to occur when there are multiple instance is interesting. I would definitely focus on that; is it really true? how can multiple instances affect each other (socket/network layer)? what is the output pipe? BTW. What socket API are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem I had recently.

If your program accepts data and buffers it internally without any limits, then it may be reading and buffering faster than it can output the data. In that case, memory use will continue to increase without limit.

The more instances of the program that you run, the slower each instance will go, and the faster the buffers will increase.

This may or may not be your problem, but without more information it is the best I can do.

Comment: This was closest to accurate.  I was suppose to output data once every x seconds (confugred by a config file). But due to a bug the counter which stored my timeout time was incrementing at startup incorectly so I was storing a minute + of data.  Extra strain on system caused the bug that incremented my timeout counter to occure more often at startup.  I would like to thank Plasma for mentioning massif which set me in the right direction. I thought memcheck was telling me that there wasn't much memory used so I didn't look at internal memory use; I apparntly misread memcheck.

Answer (score 2):

You should first look for soft leak. It happens when some static or singleton gradually increases some buffer or container and collects trash into it. Technically it is not leak but its effects are as bad.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you give a try with MemoryScape? This tool does a pretty good job in memory leak detection. It's not free but given the time and energy spent, it is worth trying.